# Iterating through arrays to find highest pairing

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

Say I have an array of arrays that contains children (as the 0th element of each array) and their parent (as the 1st element of each array), like so:

```
[[child, parent], [child, parent], [child, parent]]
```

Here is a real example:

```
[[Mary, Dan], [Dan, Steven], [Steven, Craig], [Janice, Keith]]
```

Mary is the child of Dan, Dan is the child of Steven, Steven is the child of Craig. Janice and Keith are not connected to the family. Each child will only have one parent. Also, the pairings represent all possible pairings for the family. As neither Janice nor Keith are in any other child/parent pairing for the family, we know they are not connected.

Given that Mary is the input, how do I create a loop that returns Craig as the oldest ancestor of Mary?

I was thinking of a while loop that takes input as Mary, then starts the loop over with Dan, then starts the loop over with Steven, then starts the loop over with Craig, then upon not finding a match, returns Craig. However, I want it to work on a theoretically unlimited length of ancestors. I feel like this should be simple but I haven't found a solution that works, besides writing a bunch of for loops within each other that wouldn't work on a list of 100 ancestors.

Comment: Sorry I need to add one rule: The pairings represent all possible pairings for the family. As neither Janice nor Keith are in any other child/parent pairing for the family, we know they are not connected

Comment: Can a child have more than one parent?

Comment: nope only one parent per child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary (child to parent) from your array and use your `while` loop approach:

```
data = [['Mary', 'Dan'], ['Dan', 'Steven'], ['Steven', 'Craig'], ['Janice', 'Keith']]
tree = {child: parent for child, parent in data}

def oldest_ancestor(child):
    parent = child
    while tree.get(parent, None) is not None:
        parent = tree[parent]
    return parent

print(oldest_ancestor('Mary')) # Craig
```

Comment: How can I account for a null value in the array? For example: [['Mary', 'Dan'], ['Dan', 'Steven'], ['Steven', 'Craig'], ['Mary', None]]

Comment: @AshleyO I think you can just filter those names out when building the dictionary: `tree = {child: parent for child, parent in data if parent}`.

Comment: @AshleyO Although the function as it is should work fine with `None` parents.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
data = [['Mary', 'Dan'], ['Dan', 'Steven'], ['Steven', 'Craig'], ['Janice', 'Keith']]


def get_oldest_ancestor(d, source):
    def getParent(d, source):
        return next((parent for child, parent in d if child == source), None)

    while True:
        parent = getParent(d, source)
        if parent:
            source = parent
        else:
            return source


ancestor = get_oldest_ancestor(data, 'Mary')
print(ancestor)
```

**Output**

```
Craig
```

Comment: This does not work, i.e. data = [['Mary', 'Janice'],['Mary','Dan'], ['Dan', 'Steven'], ['Steven', 'Craig'], ['Janice', 'Keith']]

Comment: The example has more than one parent per child, as specified in the comments this cannot happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the child's parent with every other child to see if it is present.

```
family = [["Mary", "Dan"], ["Dan", "Steven"], ["Steven", "Craig"],["Janice", "Keith"]]



def oldestAncestor(child):
    directParent = ""
    for pair in family:
        if pair[0] == child:
            directParent = pair[1]
            pass
        if directParent == pair[0]:
            directParent = pair[1]
            pass
        pass
    return directParent

print (oldestAncestor("Mary"))
```

answer

```
Craig
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use [`bfs_predecessors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors) algorithm from `networkx`:

```
In[43]:
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
edges=[['Mary', 'Dan'], ['Dan', 'Steven'], ['Steven', 'Craig'], ['Janice', 'Keith']]
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
df = pd.DataFrame(edges, columns=['child','parent'])
df['oldest_descendant'] = df['child'].apply(lambda x: list(nx.bfs_predecessors(G,x))[-1][0])
df
Out[43]: 
    child  parent oldest_descendant
0    Mary     Dan             Craig
1     Dan  Steven             Craig
2  Steven   Craig             Craig
3  Janice   Keith             Keith
```

I use a pandas dataframe just to illustrate things easier but, so here I make a digraph from the pairings so I can use the algorithm. I populate a df using these edges and then add the 'oldest_desendant' column, this just calls the algorithm on each child and I convert the generator object to a list which returns a list of tuples:

```
In[41]:
list(nx.bfs_predecessors(G,'Mary'))

Out[41]: [('Dan', 'Mary'), ('Steven', 'Dan'), ('Craig', 'Steven')]
```

So I just index the first element of the last tuple using `[-1][0]`